# Session Variable Not Being Saved When Using Wizard Control ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, variables, controls, wizard

I have a wizard control. When someone clicks a button within the wizard control I automatically advance to the next step (rather than forcing them to click next). However, this seems to cause the session state variable not to be saved. I've done some research and noticed that Response.Redirect does hard redirects that truncate page execution - and that you can add a false parameter to prevent this...what I'm wondering is if the wizard control is doing the same thing and if so, if I can add a parameter to this as well?
Dave.

Comment: Mhhh, I don't think it's related to that. Maybe you're resetting the value of that property somewhere else?

Comment: @Claudio - I think you are right. I've discovered that what is actually occurring is that it stores the Session variable the first time I run through the wizard, but if I go back to the beginning (say b/c I chose a wrong value) and click on a button again - it still maintains the same value in session state!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my instance it ended up having to do with the point at which the button click control launched. e.g., if in the wizard I clicked a button and it loaded the next page in the wizard it would load the page_load before it would set the session variable in the button_click event. by moving the utilization of the session variable later in the loading process (after page_load), the button_click event triggers first.